# Problems building javax.usb - reference implementation and linux implementation

Tags: java, libusb

For javax.usb, there are three modules:

- javax-usb
- javax-usb-ri
- javax-usb-ri-linux

The faq indicates that in order to use javax-usb, one must build all three modules.  Each module has an associated tarball.  I've downloaded each of them and unpacked them.  So I have a folder with each of these folders in it.

In a console, I enter the javax-usb folder and enter

```
ant all
```

and the jar gets built.  No problem.  Everything's perfect!

I enter the javax-usb-ri colder and enter

```
ant all
```

and it errors out indicating:

```
[javac] Compiling 50 source files to /home/nato/javax/javax-usb-ri/src
[javac] /home/nato/javax/javax-usb-ri/src/com/ibm/jusb/DefaultUsbInterfacePolicy.java:12: package javax.usb does not exist
[javac] import javax.usb.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] /home/nato/javacrap/javax/javax-usb-ri/src/com/ibm/jusb/DefaultUsbInterfacePolicy.java:18: cannot find symbol
```

and a bunch more errors like that.
I figure that this is because the jar that I made is not on the classpath.  Okay.
So I check, and I don't have a classpath environment variable.  My understanding is that then the classpath is just ./  So I copy the jsr80.jar file to the javax-usb-ri folder and to the javax-usb-ri/src folder and a few other places and it doesn't seem to matter where I put it, I can't get it to build.

This is frustrating.  Is this the best way to get Java to use libusb?  Is there some maven repository with a better/more integrated java solution?

If not, can you suggest what's wrong with my attempted build process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the path of the jar to Ant via the 'lib' option.

Try changing the command as:

`ant all -lib < path of jar>`.

For example, if the jsr80.jar file is kept in /home/user1/myjars; then the command would be

```
ant all -lib /home/user1/myjars/
```